# Catching a "character-typed" event in Outlook

Tags: c#, com, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm working on an Outlook addon and I'm wondering if there is a way to receive an event notification when a particular character, or set of characters, is typed? For example, say I want something to happen as soon as the user types '$' in a new mail item, is it possible to register for such an event?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there no events provided, that you can use. But you can try use Win32 API to get the key press event.